# Scheme get last command in guile

Tags: scheme, lisp, guile

Normally in a terminal (or any other command prompt I've previously used) I'll press the up key to get the last entered command. However, when doing that in the `guile` interpreter, I just get:

```
scheme@(guile-user) [1]> ^[[A
```

What is the easiest way to get the last entered-in command in guile?

Comment: Many command-line REPLs have pretty limited functionality. If you are going to code in any Lisp, emacs is really nice and worth getting comfortable in. For Common Lisp, SLIME is fantastic; for Schemes I would recommend using [Geiser](https://nongnu.org/geiser/). Geiser will even work for Racket, although Racket-Mode seems a little nicer these days for that. All of these give you more functionality at the REPL (e.g. CTRL plus arrow keys to navigate history), which can run in an emacs buffer. Bit of a learning curve, but well worth it.

Answer (score 7):

Command-line REPLs are often feature-poor. For Guile, a better experience can be had by, for example, running under [Geiser](https://nongnu.org/geiser/) in emacs. This allows a running REPL in an emacs buffer, with much better control. As a long-term solution, I would suggest learning how to do something like this.

There is a bit of a learning curve to get productive in emacs (not as much as people often seem to fear, though). Fortunately, Guile provides a solution for those who wish to stick with the regular Guile REPL.

While it is not enabled by default, [Guile can make use of the GNU Readline library](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.html#Readline). This allows navigation of the REPL expression history via the up- and down-arrow keys. Assuming that you have installed the GNU Readline library, you can enable this feature from the REPL:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (use-modules (ice-9 readline))
scheme@(guile-user)> (activate-readline)
```

[When Guile is started in interactive mode, it first loads the `.guile` init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/guile.html#Init-File) from the users home directory. You can take advantage of this by adding the above two lines to the `.guile` file (create a new `.guile` file for this purpose if one does not already exist):

```
;;; Guile Scheme Init File

;; Activate Readline
;; allows navigation of expression history in REPL
(use-modules (ice-9 readline))
(activate-readline)
```

After updating the `.guile` file, whenever Guile is run in interactive mode, you will automatically have the Readline functionality.

Comment: With Guix, I had to run `guix -i guile-readline` in order for the `.guile` tip to work.

Comment: @vivicat -- that is strange. You mean that you could activate readline functionality from the REPL, but you couldn't activate it via your `.guile` init file until you installed the guix package? I don't use guix, but it sounds like something else may be responsible.

Comment: Mm no, i just didn't phrase it well. I couldn't import the readline module at all until I installed that package.